# Android listview how to scroll selected item to the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to create a ListView in Android. When I click on an item, I want it to scroll it over to the top. How can I do that? Here is the Activity class that I am trying out, item selections works fine but it does not scroll over to the top

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        //l.setSelection(2);

        Toast.makeText(this, position + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //l.smoothScrollToPosition(5);

    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29345217/1881527

Answer (score 12):

Use this. Will scroll the item in position smoothly to the top of the listview.

```
int duration = 500;  //miliseconds
int offset = 0;      //fromListTop

listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);
```

- descrease duration to make scrolling faster

Comment: thanks @MohsenBahmanpoor. is quite simple i can say and worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method `setSelection (int position)`.

Sets the currently selected item. To support accessibility subclasses that override this method must invoke the `overridden` super method first.

Answer (score 1):

According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18133295/3225458, you should try to `post` smooth scrolling:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(final ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    l.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            l.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(this, position + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but there was no scrolling at all

Answer (score 0):

try this one:-

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                int duration = 500; // miliseconds
                int offset = 0;
                yourListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(arg2, offset, duration);
                yourListView.setSelection(arg2);
            }
        });
```