# Scroll gridview so a position is at the exact center

Tags: android, gridview

I am making an android app and it uses a `GridView`. I made a search button so people can go to a specefic position in the `GridView`.
I am currently using:

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
```

But in that doesn't center the position to the middle of the `GridView`.
This is what I want in an illustration:
[image]

Actually the problem is that the `GridView` stops scrolling from the moment the correct item is visible. Which means it will have a different place when scrolling up or down.

Comment: Have you tried using setSelection(), I've had some issues with smoothScrollToPosition() in the past

Comment: Yes, but then you lose the nice scroll animation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar issues, so I manual compute it. `v` is the View to be centered:

```
   Rect rect = new Rect();
   mMediaGridView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

   mMediaGridView.smoothScrollBy(v.getBottom()  - mMediaGridView.getScrollY()-rect.centerY()+v.getHeight()/2, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of this problem: 
[android: smoothScrollToPosition() not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431832/android-smoothscrolltoposition-not-working-correctly)

I've experienced an issue like this before with listviews, I used setSelection() to solve it.

Comment: Not fixed, when I start scrolling from the bottom my item is on the top, when I start scrolling from the top my item is on the bottom.