# How to scrollto an offset inside recyclerview?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

How do I scroll to a particular position with an offset inside recyclerview?

I have used

```
public LinearLayoutManager linearlayoutmanager;
linearlayoutmanager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, scrolled);
```

Also I have used scrollto

```
mRecyclerView.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
```

Also I have used smoothScrolltoposition

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled);
```

But none seems to working for me.

If anyone knows anything about this please could you help me

**UPDATE**

Function where i am setting adapter of my Recyclerview

```
public void Nearby_Search_requestData() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client = MySSLTrust.trustcert(getActivity());

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(SEARCH_MERCHANT_ENDPOINT).setClient(new OkClient(client)).build();
    final RetrofitInterface api = adapter.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    if (api != null) {
        api.post_Nearby_Search(page.toString(), new Callback<Nearby_Search_All>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final Nearby_Search_All server_data, Response response) {
                if (server_data.getSuccess() == 1) {
                    if (server_data.getResults().size() == 0) {
                        if (page != 0) {
                            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(firstVis);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("hii", "zero");
            //                NO_MERCHANT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mAdapter = new searchrecyclerviewadapter(getActivity(), data, font);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("scroll", "hii");
            //            NO_MERCHANT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        if (server_data.getSize() > server_data.getResults().size()) {
                            stay_on_this_page = true;
                        } else {
                            stay_on_this_page = false;
                        }
                        if (page == 0) {
                            prev_total = 0;
                            data.clear();
                            Log.d("hii", "Page is zero " + prev_total);
                            list_size = server_data.getSize();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("hii", "prev_total is " + prev_total + " Size is " + server_data.getSize() + " page is " + page);
                            prev_total = server_data.getSize() * page;
                            Log.d("hii", "Now prev_total is " + prev_total);
                        }
                        total_curr = server_data.getResults().size();

                        Log.d("hii", "first place is " + server_data.getResults().get(0).getShop_name());

                        for (int i = 0; i < total_curr; i++) {
                            information current = new information();
                            current.title = server_data.getResults().get(i).getShop_name();
                            String street = server_data.getResults().get(i).getAddress().getStreet();
                            String area = server_data.getResults().get(i).getAddress().getArea();
                            current.Address = street + " " + area;
                            String[] splited = area.split(",");
                            current.area1 = splited[1];
                            current.type = server_data.getResults().get(i).getShop_type();
                            current.rating = server_data.getResults().get(i).getRating();
                            current.distance = server_data.getResults().get(i).getDistance();
                            current.jeb_no = server_data.getResults().get(i).getJeb_no();
                            current.total_photos = server_data.getResults().get(i).getTotal_photos();
                            if (current.total_photos  == 0) {

                            } else if (current.total_photos  == 1) {
                                current.photo_1 = server_data.getResults().get(i).getPhotos().getPhoto_1();
                            } else if (current.total_photos  == 2) {
                                current.photo_1 = server_data.getResults().get(i).getPhotos().getPhoto_1();
                                current.photo_2 = server_data.getResults().get(i).getPhotos().getPhoto_2();
                            } else {
                                current.photo_1 = server_data.getResults().get(i).getPhotos().getPhoto_1();
                                current.photo_2 = server_data.getResults().get(i).getPhotos().getPhoto_2();
                            }
                            data.add(current);
                        }
                        if (adapterinitialised) {
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            mAdapter = new searchrecyclerviewadapter(getActivity(), data, font);
                          //  mAdapter.setClickListener(Search.class);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                            adapterinitialised = true;
                        }
                    }
                 //   mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(firstVis);
                    Log.d("scroll", "hee");
                    scrolled = scrolled + 10;
                    Log.d("scroll", "scrolled: " + scrolled);
                    // ALL BELOW CODE I HAVE TRIED FOR SCROLLING BUT NONE WAS HELPFUL
                /*    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled);

                            // or do mRecyclerView.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
                        }
                    });
                    */
                 //   l.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, scrolled);
                //    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled);
                //    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, scrolled);
                //    l.scrollToPosition();
                //        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrolled);
                //    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, scrolled);
                //    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, 10);
                //    mRecyclerView.scrollTo(0, 10);

                } else {
                    Log.d("hii", server_data.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), server_data.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Log.d("hii", "failure");
                Log.e("hii", retrofitError.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), retrofitError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d("hii", "api null");
    }
}
```

Comment: try `RecyclerView#scrollBy(int x, int y) `

Comment: no i it is not working ?? also as i am putting x as 0 it will scroll vertically ??

Comment: did you try it? if so, what did you try? what was the result?

Comment: nothing scrolled i was at position 0 ??

Comment: just try `mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, 100);` and see what happens

Comment: formatted as code, not quote

Comment: no nothing happened can you pls do me a favor can you try to use scrollby and see if it worked ?

Comment: i have stucked on this same problem any leads ??

Comment: just tried `scrollBy`, works just fine

Comment: can you show me your whole java class code ??

Comment: ok what happens if you call `mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, 100);`? how many items do you have in your RecyclerView.Adapter? how many are visible?

Comment: nothing happens my i see my list starting from position 0, 3 items are visible

Comment: can you show me your code on github or anywhere please i really need help ???

Comment: if you want to use `scrollBy` just after calling `mRecyclerView.setAdapter` you need to call it inside `Runnable`, like `mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {...`

Comment: yea but it is taking some time i dont know why ??

Comment: i want to scrolled it to immediatly user see list

Comment: it is not taking any time, it is called immediately

Comment: my list first loads then after some near around 1 sec my list scroll to my desired position i dont want this delay thing ??

Comment: there is no delay: add `Log.d` before calling `post` method and another `Log.d` inside `run` method and you will see

Comment: i m telling you after my recycer view list shows it takes 1 sec then it go to my desired offset location if you wanna check then you can try it out by yourself ??

Comment: scrolby is not working inside runnable i am using smothscrolltoposition but it is again showing delay

Comment: `scrollBy` is working like that: https://codeshare.io/EXFKs

Answer (score 13):

Here is my answer. Set

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);//or HORIZONTAL
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
adapter = new Adapter(...);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This provides direction of your RecyclerView, adapter and data (replace `...` with context, list, array or another data needed). Than set

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
```

Now the interesting thing:

- this will scroll to position and place it at the top of the list in case of VERTICAL linear layout manager an at the left with HORIZONTAL
- if offset is positive, VERTICAL layout manager will scroll this position downwards by `offset` in pixels (rightwards with HORIZONTAL layout manager)
- if position is 0 and offset is positive, than nothing will happen, because RecyclerView does not have any items positioned at the top of your 0 position (at the left with HORIZONTAL layout manager)
- if position is 0 and offset is negative, than VERTICAL layout manager will scroll 0 position upwards by offset in pixels (leftwards with HORIZONTAL)
- also nothing will happen if RecyclerView's height (width with HORIZONTAL orientation) is smaller than screen size
- also it will scroll wrongly if position to scroll to is last or near the end and its height (width in case of HORIZONTAL orientation) is relatively small

Hope this will clarify situation for you with RecyclerView's layout manager

Comment: It's interesting that only `scrollToPositionWithOffset` works, instead of for example `recyclerView.scrollTo` or `scrollBy`. However, how to solve the issues when near to the bottom? I have issues in these cases - doesn't have to be super-near to the bottom, starts at a fairly large distance - and the height isn't that small.

Comment: I mean isn't there any method to scroll a recycler view (more specifically when initialized - appears to work in other cases) reliably? This is crazy...

Comment: I didn't understood your requirements ("However, how to solve the issues when near to the bottom"), but quick suggestion is to add padding to recyclerview for bottom and add clipToPadding=false to scroll pass the bottom item. And, if my answer was "correct" - please mark it as corect.

Comment: @aman verma, please consider to mark my answer as correct if it resolves your question

Answer (score 3):

I believe what your looking for is to run this scroll but do so by posting a runnable on your `RecyclerView` and run the smoothScrollToPosition there:

```
 // use either post or postDelayed
 mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled);

            // or do mRecyclerView.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

if you would like to skip the delay:

```
 mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled);

            // or do mRecyclerView.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i don't get it, why are you using threads why doesn't just  mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled) work ??

Comment: @amanverma creating a new Runnable does not use a new Thread unless you explicitly pass that Runnable to a Thread

Comment: yea but why using this doesnt mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrolled) alone sufficient why use runnable ??

Comment: @amanverma in simplistic terms, the UI is not ready to scroll to a position as its setting up, so posting a new Runnable to do the work will account for this. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431832/android-smoothscrolltoposition-not-working-correctly

Comment: Yep this is working but i dot know why normal scrolltoposition is not working also scrolling is happening but after some seconds can you pls tell me why is this happeing and how to remove this.

Comment: @amanverma this is due to the postDelayed method, and the 1000 which is 1 second delay. if you just switch to post(new Runnable(){...}) dropping the millis argument, it should happen fairly quickly, and if your list is short you may not see the effect of it

Comment: but it is taking some time ?? thats why i dont wanna use runable but dont know how to do this ??

Comment: @amanverma please see the updated answer where i show the post method, this does not take some time

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
}, 10);


recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

According with the documentation you should use scrollToPosition.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)

Comment: i have used but it didn't work     public LinearLayoutManager linearlayoutmanager; linearlayoutmanager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, scrolled);

Comment: but i also need an offset

Comment: The offset start from 0, right? You can keep the position in a variable, and when you scroll your offset shoud be: offset + getPosition of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#getPosition(android.view.View)

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top

Answer (score -3):

This may work

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

---

***0**, in this case, represents the position in the adapter*

Comment: "position - Scroll to this adapter position" that is not an offset.

Comment: Re-done the downvote. But still, I don't think it is an answer to the question. :)