# How to set listview scroll one item by one item

Tags: android, listview, scroll

is it possible to set listview scroll one by one?
can you give an example.

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707568/listview-scroll-one-by-one

Comment: don't ask these type of simple question. It is already present in stackoverflow. Try to search in stackoverflow and get answer. If you ask these type of question , you will get more down votes. try to get answer in stackoverflow. If you didn't get , then ask here.

Comment: You should do R&D before posting questions

Comment: sorry, but i already tried that & it doesn't work.

Comment: So what didn't work about it?  What error did you get?  What else have you tried?  The more information you provide the more likely you are to get help, and the less likely it is that your question gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

hide the scrollbar:

```
listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

documentation: [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)
Example: [example ListView](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php)

Comment: how is the example relevant ?

Comment: Is this an answer to above qustion??